# Where is this Indian-style palace with a large pool?

Tags: where-on-earth, identify-this, architecture

Trying to figure out where this place is:

[image]

Comment: if you like the answer you may [accept the answer](http://travel.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 18):

This is [Sun City Resort](http://www.sun-city-south-africa.com/) in South Africa, opened in 1979, specifically it's the [Palace of the Lost City](http://www.sun-city-south-africa.com/palace-of-the-lost-city/photo-gallery).

There's some apartheid-era [history](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sun_City,_North_West#History) to it (thanks @Andrew Grimm) but it's still open today.

You can use a service like [TinEye](http://tineye.com/search/4a716f86fdff82360ce92bd769c5f9a7fbfee36b/) or [Google image search](https://www.google.ca/webhp?output=search&tbm=isch&tbo=u) to search for pictures like this on the Internet, then from there look for captions or any relevant text to help identify it

Comment: Wow! Thanks so much.  I've never tried to find a place from a picture before.  Thanks again!!!

Comment: @Brenda you're welcome, fun question to research :)

Comment: I have searched all day and then came across this site.  I hate when u see something interesting but there is no mention of where it is :(

Comment: Is the place tainted nowadays because of past apartheid? https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sun_City_(song)

Comment: @Brenda how did you try to search?? I went to https://images.google.com , clicked the little camera icon, entered the URL and presto! it found the place. There are browser extensions making it even easier.

Comment: I went there for a conference post- Apartheid. I recognized the building from the picture easily enough.